# Reporting Services Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to configure Reporting Services on a dev server so we can use it for development, but it is not working out for me.  When I try to access the Reports page, I get the following error:

User 'ServerName/UserName' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this, does Reporting Services need a virtual directory?  If so, does anybody have a link on how to configure it?  When I created the ReportingServices database, it made me a dbo by default, I'm a sysadmin on sql Server, so the permissions should be good.

I'm running sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by going to the report manager on the server hosting reporting services by using the link http://localhost/reports.  Once I was there then I clicked on home and configured the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> > Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

If you are running IE on the server on which you installed SSRS, make sure that you right click and run IE as administrator.

Have you tried this from other machines? IF you are getting the same results from multiple machines, then go through the steps in Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Configuration Tools -> Reporting Services Configuration Manager. Here you can reset most of the basic SSRS configuration.

You don't need a virtual directory: SSRS no longer uses IIS: it is built directly on http.sys.

Comment: I tried running as administrator in IE, that didn't work.....I'm trying to uninstall reporting services and reinstall right now.